# Vite Web Component not appearing in DOM after importing

Tags: vue.js, vite, web-component

I've built a simple web component and am running into an issue at the finish line.
The app builds and runs properly; everything works fine when I test locally.
I've created a simple html file into which I've imported the web component with:

`<script src="http://localhost:5173/dist/web-component.js"></script>` (in head)

`<web-component></web-component>` (in body)

Upon opening the page in chrome the script tag doesn't `404` and following the link opens a file that properly aligns with what was populated in `dist/web-component.js` after the initial build.

Everything looks good.
However, in the DOM the `<web-component></web-component>` is empty and lacks all functionality.

Below are some relevant files:

**main.ce.ts**

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import WebComp from './WebComponent.ce.vue'
const WebComponent = defineCustomElement(WebComp)

customElements.define('web-component', WebComponent)
```

**vite.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes('web-component')
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: './src/main.ce.ts',
      name: 'web-component',
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: 'web-component'
    }
  }
})
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
       "./*"
      ]
     },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

again, everything runs fine and works locally, but the imported web component is empty